# Why is my stack-based implementation of this code so much slower than recursion?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have a tree whose nodes store either -1 or a non-negative integer that is the name of a vertex. Each vertex appears at most once within the tree. The following function is a bottleneck in my code:

Version A:

```
void node_vertex_members(node *A, vector<int> *vertexList){
   if(A->contents != -1){
      vertexList->push_back(A->contents);
   }
   else{
      for(int i=0;i<A->children.size();i++){
          node_vertex_members(A->children[i],vertexList);
      }
   }
}
```

Version B:

```
void node_vertex_members(node *A, vector<int> *vertexList){
   stack<node*> q;
   q.push(A);
   while(!q.empty()){
      int x = q.top()->contents;
      if(x != -1){
         vertexList->push_back(x);
         q.pop();
      }
      else{
         node *temp = q.top();
         q.pop();
         for(int i=temp->children.size()-1; i>=0; --i){
            q.push(temp->children[i]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

For some reason, version B takes significantly longer to run than version A, which I did not expect. What might the compiler be doing that's so much more clever than my code? Put another way, what am I doing that's so inefficient? Also perplexing to me is that if I try anything such as checking in version B whether the children's contents are -1 before putting them on the stack, it slows down dramatically (almost 3x). For reference, I am using g++ in Cygwin with the -O3 option.

**Update:**

I was able to match the recursive version using the following code (version C):

```
node *node_list[65536];

void node_vertex_members(node *A, vector<int> *vertex_list){
   int top = 0;
   node_list[top] = A;
   while(top >= 0){
      int x = node_list[top]->contents;
      if(x != -1){
         vertex_list->push_back(x);
         --top;
      }
      else{
         node* temp = node_list[top];
         --top;
         for(int i=temp->children.size()-1; i>=0; --i){
            ++top;
            node_list[top] = temp->children[i];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Obvious downsides are the code length and the magic number (and associated hard limit). And, as I said, this only matches the version A performance. I will of course be sticking with the recursive version, but I am satisfied now that it was basically STL overhead biting me.

Comment: When you use recursion, the compiler **knows** there's an implicit stack. And it will optimize. When you use an explicit stack, apparently it can't deduce you do. Don't try to second guess the compiler ;)

Comment: Oh, and BTW use references instead of pointers (in particular, as the arguments of the function).

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe something that will help: (I'm feeling in a hackish mood today, so appropriate suggestions follow): if you can reasonably limit the size of your tree, just store it in an array and loop over all of it. Also, if it happens much that whole subtrees are -1 (or alternatively: do not contain -1 at all), store such an indication in each vertex, and either stop recursion (if the whole subtree is -1) or from that vertex down stop checking `contents != -1` (if the whole subtree is >0).

Comment: Another suggestion: whenever you add a node, store a reference to it in a global array (preferably) or list. Since your recursion visits the entire tree, and since order doesn't matter (I think, I am not sure how you use vertexList), just loop over the node-reference array instead of recursing thru the tree.

Comment: Since I don't have your whole program, I can't run it under GDB and pinpoint the issue. However, I would fully expect it to be in all the `push_back`, `push`, and `pop`s you are doing, especially when used with vectors instead of simple lists. Those operations run off and do a ton of memory allocating, deallocating, copying, etc.

Comment: It's because it's a `stack<node*, deque<node*>>`, not a `stack<node*, vector<node*>>`.

Comment: I'd find it interesting if you were able to post a compete example program (especially if it included example data) - even if that program had to be external to SO, like on ideone or github.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Version A has one significant advantage: far smaller code size.

Version B has one significant disadvantage: memory allocation for the stack elements.  Consider that the stack starts out empty and has elements pushed into it one by one.  Every so often, a new allocation will have to be made for the underlying deque.  This is an expensive operation, and it may be repeated a few times for each call of your function.

Edit: here's the assembly generated by `g++ -O2 -S` with GCC 4.7.3 on Mac OS, run through `c++filt` and annotated by me:

```
versionA(node*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*):
LFB609:
        pushq   %r12
LCFI5:
        movq    %rsi, %r12
        pushq   %rbp
LCFI6:
        movq    %rdi, %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
LCFI7:
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        cmpl    $-1, %eax ; if(A->contents != -1)
        jne     L36 ; vertexList->push_back(A->contents)
        movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
        xorl    %r8d, %r8d
        movl    $1, %ebx
        movq    16(%rdi), %rax
        subq    %rcx, %rax
        sarq    $3, %rax
        testq   %rax, %rax
        jne     L46 ; i < A->children.size()
        jmp     L35
L43: ; for(int i=0;i<A->children.size();i++)
        movq    %rdx, %rbx
L46:
        movq    (%rcx,%r8,8), %rdi
        movq    %r12, %rsi
        call    versionA(node*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*)
        movq    8(%rbp), %rcx
        leaq    1(%rbx), %rdx
        movq    16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rbx, %r8
        subq    %rcx, %rax
        sarq    $3, %rax
        cmpq    %rbx, %rax
        ja      L43 ; continue
L35:
        popq    %rbx
LCFI8:
        popq    %rbp
LCFI9:
        popq    %r12
LCFI10:
        ret

L36: ; vertexList->push_back(A->contents)
LCFI11:
        movq    8(%rsi), %rsi
        cmpq    16(%r12), %rsi ; vector::size == vector::capacity
        je      L39
        testq   %rsi, %rsi
        je      L40
        movl    %eax, (%rsi)
L40:
        popq    %rbx
LCFI12:
        addq    $4, %rsi
        movq    %rsi, 8(%r12)
        popq    %rbp
LCFI13:
        popq    %r12
LCFI14:
        ret
L39: ; slow path for vector to expand capacity
LCFI15:
        movq    %rdi, %rdx
        movq    %r12, %rdi
        call    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)
        jmp     L35
```

That's fairly succinct and at a glance seems fairly free of "speed bumps."  When I compile with -O3 I get an unholy mess, with unrolled loops and other fun stuff.  I don't have time to annotate Version B right now, but suffice to say it is more complex due to many deque functions and scribbling on a lot more memory.  No surprise it's slower.

Comment: I considered the STL allocation and tried this with a global stack and a reserve large enough that it would never be reallocated. It is still slower. I left that out as part of the example, but your answer is totally valid. I still wonder what other optimizations the compiler might be performing.

Comment: Do you know how to generate and read assembly code?  That should make it more clear.  If you don't, you can post your definition of the node class and maybe someone will take a shot at it.

Comment: I do, or did, years ago, but the actual situation is somewhat messier than what I posted. I'll eventually dig into it far enough to understand the assembly; I only posted here hoping for some insight, especially into what I might be doing sub-optimally. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of `q` in version B is significantly greater than the maximum recursion depth in version A.  That could make your cache performance quite a bit less efficient.

(version A: depth is `log(N)/log(b)`, version B: queue length hits `b*log(N)/log(b)`)

Answer (score 1):

The second code is slower because it's maintaining a second dynamic set data structure in addition to the collection that is being returned. That involves more memory allocations, more object initializations, more list insertions and deletions.

However, the algorithm in the second code is more flexible: it can be trivially modified to give you a breadth-first traversal instead of depth first, whereas recursion only performs depth-first traversal. (Well, it can go depth first, but the change is not quite as trivial; see comment at the end.)

Since the job is to traverse everything and collect some nodes, perhaps the depth first traversal is better, assuming you don't want depth-first order.

But in situations where you are searching for a node which satisfies some condition, it may be more appropriate to implement a breadth-first search.  If the tree is infinite (because it is not a data structure, but a search tree of possibilities, such as future moves in a game or whatever), it may be **intractable** to do depth-first, because there is no bottom.  In some situations, it is desirable to find a node which is close to the root, not just any node. A depth-first search can take a long time to find a node which is close to the root of the tree. If the tree is deep, but usually the desired node is found not far from the root, a depth-first search can waste a lot of time, even if the recursion mechanism which implements it is fast.

> Recursion can do breadth-first, by iterative deepening: recurse to a maximum depth of 1, then recurse from the top again, this time to a maxmum depth of 2, and so on. The queue based traversal just has to change the order in which it adds nodes to the work queue.

Comment: This is true; in fact, I have another version which is FIFO, in a queue, and it performs slightly worse; because of the way my tree is constructed, a breadth-first traversal makes the queue blow up.

Comment: @EricTressler: How can the queue blow up? It needs no more elements than are already in the tree.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: That's all that I meant -- expanding more than I'd like. Ideally, it should always be much smaller than the size of the tree.

Comment: @EricTressler: Then all you need is a circular array of sufficient size, with enqueue and dequeue pointers. I guarantee you, it will run the socks off your two swatches of code.